# No event on barcode scan in xamarin Android app

Tags: android, xamarin.android, socketmobile

I'm developing an xamarin android app to use the socketmobile CHS 7 barcode scanner. Using the simpleEntry andoid sample application i'm not receiving the OnDecodedData event. I do get the OnError, OnScanApiInitializeComplete events. The scanner is set for SSP mode, and I do get the scan data in to the editText field. I'm using a Nexus 7 tablet running Android 6.0 API 23.

Comment: did you try anything? show some code please!

Comment: I have it working now. I didn't have bluetooth permissions turned on the android manifest. Also i found that i needed to turn on the scanner after the application started. if the scanner is on and connected to the device before the app starts then it doesn't work.